What is this style of lock called?
I would like to know the proper name / nomenclature so that I can Google it.

Key indicates it is a Schlage product
bolt is annotated in red square
round keyway is silver



The lock mechanism appears to be a narrow-stile swring bolt, commonly used in glass doors for businesses.
The lock cylinder is almost certainly not from Schlage since it doesn't carry their brand name. It may still accept an SC1 or similar key; they're common.

Since it is unlabeled, it is probably a cheap no-name importer. I wouldn't search for it; I would get a good cylinder that can be keyed to accept the current key. Assuming they aren't using gratuitously different spacings, which I have seen happen

A search term: Narrow Backset Mortise Lock

@AloysiusDefenestrate: That will get them to the type of lock. If they are asking about the lock cylinder (as they did in a followup question), it's a mortise cylinder of specific body length.

.. and, I should have said, with a specific tailpiece to work with that lock mechanism. For various reasons, tailpieces are not as well standardized as you might expect, but most lock manufacturers make provision for installing the one that is needed. You may or may not be able to transplant the proper tailpiece from the old lock to the new one; generally yes but not always.
